# Adjust Balance When Playing Audio in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Is there a way to adjust the left/right balance when playing a sound in C# using the built in [SoundPlayer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx)?  I don't want to adjust the overall system balance, just the balance for the sound the program is playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound Player a simple lib to play wave files so dont think it has the capability. You can check the AXWindowsMediaPlayer for advance functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `SoundPlayer`, you can create your `Stream`-derived class that will wrap around original wave file, but will manipulate sound samples and adjust left and right volume to your liking.